# Running `ALTER TABLE` trips into a `Index PRIMARY is corrupted`

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

we've currently come across a problem when trying to run a DDL in a table which we don't know how to sort out.

Given our schema:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `some_table` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `some_uuid` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `some_text` mediumtext NOT NULL,
  `some_int` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `an_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `another_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `some_timestamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `last_executed_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `some_int` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `deleted_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `external_ref` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `deleted_at_key` varchar(20) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (coalesce(`deleted_at`,'n/a')) VIRTUAL,
  `external_ref_key` varchar(50) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (coalesce(nullif(`external_ref`,''),`an_id`)) VIRTUAL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id_UNIQUE` (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `rec_ref_unique` (`an_id`,`external_ref_key`,`deleted_at_key`),
  KEY `start_at_INDEX` (`start_at`),
  KEY `idx_an_id` (`an_id`),
  KEY `index_some_uuid` (`some_uuid`),
  KEY `idx_another_id` (`another_id`),
  KEY `external_ref_index` (`external_ref`),
  KEY `idx_deleted_at` (`deleted_at`),
  KEY `idx_last_executed_at` (`last_executed_at`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1567256 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Which has roughly 1.5M records.

This is what we run:

```
$ mycli connect ...
No port specified - defaulting to 3306
Authentication Token generated.
MySQL 5.7.33
mycli 1.25.0
Home: http://mycli.net
Bug tracker: https://github.com/dbcli/mycli/issues
Thanks to the contributor - Lennart Weller


MySQL db_writer@127.0.0.1:(none)> connect my_db
You are now connected to database "my_db" as user "db_writer"
Time: 0.076s


MySQL db_writer@127.0.0.1:my_db> ALTER TABLE some_table ADD COLUMN `a_boolean_column` BOOL DEFAULT false NOT NULL, ALGORITHM=INPLACE, LOCK=NONE;
You're about to run a destructive command.
Do you want to proceed? (y/n): y
Your call!
(1712, 'Index PRIMARY is corrupted')
```

Now, notice the:

```
(1712, 'Index PRIMARY is corrupted')
```

This happens after waiting ~45 minutes. Note that the index is not corrupted upfront, just happens during the operation.

On top of this, it happens also when running `OPTIMIZE TABLE`:

```
MySQL db_writer@127.0.0.1:my_db> optimize table some_table;
+---------------------------+----------+----------+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Table                     | Op       | Msg_type | Msg_text                                                          |
+---------------------------+----------+----------+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
| my_db.some_table          | optimize | note     | Table does not support optimize, doing recreate + analyze instead |
| my_db.some_table          | optimize | error    | Index PRIMARY is corrupted                                        |
| my_db.some_table          | optimize | status   | Operation failed                                                  |
+---------------------------+----------+----------+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
3 rows in set
Time: 926.919s

MySQL db_writer@127.0.0.1:my_db> check table subscription
+---------------------------+-------+----------+----------+
| Table                     | Op    | Msg_type | Msg_text |
+---------------------------+-------+----------+----------+
| my_db.some_table          | check | status   | OK       |
+---------------------------+-------+----------+----------+
1 row in set
Time: 6.879s
```

Does anybody know what could be going awry/what we could do to prevent this?

Comment: Yeah, but it's not relevant because the Index is not corrupted initially. Only after running the DDL.

Comment: I added some extra info, thanks :)

Comment: The problem is we can't afford to lock the table for long periods of time... what other options would we have?

Comment: Try to perform all actions via CLI, not via third-party client (which cannot even provide complete error message).

Comment: As an alternative, I often use [pt-online-schema-change](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/LATEST/pt-online-schema-change.html), which is a free tool to run schema changes without blocking client access to the table. At my last job, we used this to allow frequent schema changes, hundreds per week, even during peak hours.

Comment: At this stage, I'll give the toolkit a shot to see if it makes a difference. Thanks @BillKarwin.